# How to apply event generate to several entries

Tags: python, html, css, windows, macos

Good morning all,

I am looking to apply an event_generate to several entries, each of which comes from a different frame generated automatically.

I will try to be as clear as possible in explaining the problem. Thank you for your understanding. (I also reduced the code as much as possible)
Once the quantities added to each Entry generated automatically, I set up an event_generate on the TAB key.
Only the last Entry generated displays a result following the event_generate.So I put a break, for example at the 2nd Entry. The result is correct.I deduce that the event_generate loop works but only displays the last operation.

i make video for see the prob
[event_generate  show only the last result](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ASGMjU3gnkQ)

> ## ==================================================
>
> ```
> #                              TreeView Recettes - Rec_list
> # ==================================================
> ```

```
# --- Insertion Table Nom HV dans TreeView
def DisplayData_Recette():
    for i in Recette_DB_BackEnd.loadRecord():
        Rec_list.insert('', 'end', text=i[0], values=(i[0]))

# --- Insertion Scrollbar
scrollbar_y = Scrollbar(F_TOP_Treeview, orient='vertical')  # Ascenseur Vertical
scrollbar_y.place(x=1786, y=24, height=169)

Rec_list = ttk.Treeview(F_TOP_Treeview, selectmode="browse", columns=(1), show="headings", yscrollcommand=scrollbar_y.set)
Rec_list.place(x=1502, y=2, width=285, height=175)

scrollbar_y.config(command=Rec_list.yview)  # Ascenseur Vertical
DisplayData_Recette()


# ==================================================
#                             SelectItem_Recettes
# ==================================================
def Clear_frameSelected():
    # Supprime toutes HV sélectionnées dans FrameCalc - frame
    global Clear_var_suite
    Clear_var_suite = 1
    for i in range(0, len(var_suite)):
        var1 = var_suite[i]
        removeLabel(var1)
    var_suite[:] = []                                                                                       # Vide liste var_suite


def selectionItem_Recette(a):
    Clear_frameSelected()
    # === [Sélection - Widget Treeview Recette] ===
    global Liste
    Liste = []
    Nom_Rec = StringVar()
    Name_HV = StringVar()
    Qt_Name_HV = DoubleVar()

    curItem = Rec_list.focus()
    Liste = Rec_list.item(curItem)["values"]

    Nom_Rec.set(Liste[0])                                                                               # Variable Nom HV - 1er élément du tableau Liste
    # print("Nom_Rec -->                                                               ", Nom_Rec.get())
    # === [Recensement Nom HV selon sélection effecttué dans Table] ===
    for row in Recette_DB_BackEnd.searchDataTable(Nom_Rec.get()):
        Name_HV.set(row[2])
        Qt_Name_HV.set(row[3])
        Display_HV(Name_HV, Qt_Name_HV)
    test()

# ==================================================
#                              Evénement Treeview HElist - Auto Sélection
# ==================================================
def Display_HV(Name_HV, Qt_Name_HV):
    global L_Nom_HV

    z = -1
    F_TOP_Treeview_ID.event_add('<<Declenche>>', '<ButtonRelease-1>')
    F_TOP_Treeview_ID.after(1000, lambda: F_TOP_Treeview_ID.event_generate('<<Declenche>>'))

    for item in F_TOP_Treeview_ID.get_children():
        z = z +1
        Ligne_HElist = []

        Ligne_HElist.append(F_TOP_Treeview_ID.item(item)["values"])                 # Liste HV de la recette cible

        if Name_HV.get() == Ligne_HElist[0][1]:
            L_Nom_HV.append(Name_HV.get())
            iid = F_TOP_Treeview_ID.get_children()[z]
            F_TOP_Treeview_ID.focus(iid)
            F_TOP_Treeview_ID.selection_set(iid)
            frame = F_TOP_Treeview_ID.get_children()[z]
            F_TOP_Treeview_ID.bind('<<Declenche>>', selectItem(frame))

            valeur_qt = Qt_Name_HV.get()
            Input_gr.insert(0, valeur_qt)                                                               # Insertion des quantités correspondnates à chacune des HV
            Input_gr.config(foreground="red")


def test():

    m = List_Input_gr[0]
    m.event_add('<<Declenche0>>', '<KeyRelease-Tab>')

    j = 0
    for kt in range(0, len(List_Input_gr)):
        m = List_Input_gr[kt]
        nom = L_Nom_HV[kt]
        Qpourc = List_Qpourc[kt]
        INSp = List_INSp[kt]
        IODEp = List_IODEp[kt]
        SC = List_SC[kt]
        HD = List_HD[kt]
        iHD = List_iHD[kt]
        CD = List_CD[kt]
        iCD = List_iCD[kt]
        CH = List_CH[kt]
        iCH = List_iCH[kt]
        BM = List_BM[kt]
        iBM = List_iBM[kt]
        CC = List_CC[kt]
        iCC = List_iCC[kt]
        La = List_La[kt]
        iLa = List_iLa[kt]
        M = List_M[kt]
        iM = List_iM[kt]
        P = List_P[kt]
        iP = List_iP[kt]
        S = List_S[kt]
        iS = List_iS[kt]
        CH18 = List_CH18[kt]
        iCH18 = List_iCH18[kt]
        O = List_O[kt]
        iO = List_iO[kt]
        L = List_L[kt]
        iL = List_iL[kt]
        Ln = List_Ln[kt]
        iLn = List_iLn[kt]
        Prix_gr = List_Prix_gr[kt]
        print("- ID_Entry -->   ", m, "         Nom Entry -->   ", Entry, "         Nom HV -->  ", nom)
        Entry.focus_force(m)
        Entry.focus_set(m)

        j = j + 1
        m.after(0, lambda: m.event_generate('<<Declenche0>>'))
        m.bind('<<Declenche0>>', lambda event, obj=m: Qgr(event, obj, nom, Qpourc, INSp, IODEp, SC, HD, iHD, CD, iCD, CH, iCH, BM, iBM, CC, iCC, La, iLa, M, iM, P, iP, S, iS, CH18, iCH18, O, iO, L, iL, Ln, iLn, Prix_gr))
        print("j",j, m)

        for keyNameEvent in m.event_info():
            # print("keyNameEvent", keyNameEvent)
            print("m.event_info('<<Declenche0>>')", m.event_info('<<Declenche0>>'))
        if j > 2:
            break


def Qgr(event, obj, nom, Qpourc, INSp, IODEp, SC, HD, iHD, CD, iCD, CH, iCH, BM, iBM, CC, iCC, La, iLa, M, iM, P, iP, S, iS, CH18, iCH18, O, iO, L, iL, Ln, iLn, Prix_gr):
    ...
```

thank in advance for your time

Answer (score 0):

here, is an simple exemple
i have the same prob, the last Entry is ok. the others are only treated

> 

```
def dosomething(event, m):
    print("OUI")
    # m.focus_set()
    # m.focus()
    m.delete(0, END)
    m.after(1, lambda: m.focus_set())

def testy():

    m = List_Input_gr[0]
    m.event_add('<<Declenche0>>', '<KeyRelease-Tab>')
    for kt in range(0, len(List_Input_gr)):
        m = List_Input_gr[kt]
        print("m_in", m)
        m.after(0, lambda: m.event_generate('<<Declenche0>>'))
        m.bind('<<Declenche0>>', lambda event: dosomething(event, m))

b1 = Button(FrameCalc, text="ttttttttt", command=testy)
b1.grid(row=30, column=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's work now. I don't know if the right way. who have idea or can confirm please.
Thank you for your time

```
>   def dosomething(event, m):
        # m.focus_set()
        # m.focus()
        print("m -->1 ", m)
        m.delete(0, END)
        m.after(10, lambda: m.focus_set())
        print("OUI_1", event.widget)         # Identification du widget cible

def testy():
    m = List_Input_gr[0]
    m.event_add('<<Declenche0>>', '<KeyRelease-Tab>')
    # m.after(1, lambda m=m: m.event_generate('<<Declenche0>>'))

    for kt in range(0, len(List_Input_gr)):
        m = List_Input_gr[kt]
        print("m --> ", m)
        m.after(1, lambda m=m: m.event_generate('<<Declenche0>>'))
        # m.after(1, lambda: m.event_generate('<<Declenche0>>'))
        m.bind('<<Declenche0>>', lambda event, m=m: dosomething(event, m))
```